# Cannot get req.files using Multer, Express and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, multer

im having troubles to get req.files, always appear undefined. Im using multer, i saw anothers posts where they try with upload.single("input name"). however didn't work too.

**Controller**

```
const db = require("../database/models");

const instruments = {
    get: async (req, res) =>{
        try{
            const instruments = await db.Instruments.findAll([{include: "imagenes"},{include: "Category"}])  

            return res.send(instruments)
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    },

    post: async (req, res) => {
        try{
            
            let data = req.body;
            console.log("req", req.body)
            
            let file = req.files;
            console.log("req.file", file)
            
            let instrumento = {
                nombre: String(data.nombre),
                fabricante: String(data.fabricante),
                precio: Number(data.precio),
                categoria_id: Number(data.categoria),
                descuento: String(data.descuento),
                precioDescuento: Number(data.precioDescuento),
                texto: String(data.texto),
                fecha: data.fecha,
                image: data.images
            }

            // let instrumentosCreated = await db.Instruments.create(instrumento);

            console.log("lleuge", instrumento)

            // let imagenes = [];
            
            // Array.from(file).forEach(img => {
            //     imagenes.push(img.images);
            // })
            // //console.log("imagenes", imagenes);
            // let imagenesCreated = await imagenes.forEach(img => {  
            //     db.Image.create({
            //         url_imagen: "/"+ data.nombre +"/" + img,
            //         instrumento_id: instrumentosCreated.id
            // })
        // });

            console.log("images", imagenesCreated);
            return res.send(instrumentosCreated);
            
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = instruments
```

**Backend Configuration**

```
// ************ Require's ************

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


// ************ Data Configuration ************

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(express.json())

//CORS
app.use(cors());

// ************ Servidor ************

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => console.log("Server start in http://localhost:"+app.get("port")));

// ************ Acceso Publico ************

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../public"))); // Necesario para los archivos estáticos en el folder /public

// ************ API's ************

const apiInstrumentos = require("./routes/apiInstrumentos");

app.use(apiInstrumentos)


// ************ Router Define ************

const instrumentRouter = require("./routes/instrumentos.js");

app.use("/", instrumentRouter);
```

****Route****

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const instrumentos = require("../controllers/instrumentos");
const multer = require("multer");



// ************ Multer ************

const dest = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        let dir = path.resolve(__dirname,"../../public/uploads","instruments", String(req.body.nombre).trim().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        cb(null, dir)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:dest});

// ************ Rutas ************

router.get("/", instrumentos.get);
router.post("/guardar",[upload.any()], instrumentos.post); 


module.exports = router
```

**Form React**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';


class Form extends Component {
    
    state = {
            nombre: "",
            fabricante: "",
            precio: "",
            categoria: "",
            descuento: "",
            precioDescuento: "",
            texto: "",
            images: "",
            fecha: ""
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    
    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state)
        Axios
            .post('http://localhost:5000/guardar', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }


    render(){
    
    const {nombre,fabricante,precio,precioDescuento,texto,fecha,images} = this.state

    return(
        <main>
        <section className="titulo">
            <h2>Creación de Proyectos</h2>
        </section>
        <section className="formulario">
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler} method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                    <label htmlFor="nombreInstrumento">Nombre de tu proyecto: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" value={nombre} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label htmlFor="nombreFabricante">Nombre del fabricante:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fabricante" value={fabricante} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h3>Seleccione el tipo de instrumento</h3>
                    <fieldset id="flexRadio">
                            <label htmlFor="categoria"></label>
                            <input type="radio" className="solicitar-radio" name="categoria" value={1} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>Guitarra</p>
                            <label htmlFor="categoria"></label>
                            <input type="radio" className="solicitar-radio" name="categoria" value={2} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>Bajo</p>
                            <label htmlFor="categoria"></label>
                            <input type="radio" className="solicitar-radio" name="categoria" value={3} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>Teclados</p>
                            <label htmlFor="categoria"></label>
                            <input type="radio" className="solicitar-radio" name="categoria" value={4} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>Bateria</p>
                            <label htmlFor="categoria"></label>
                            <input type="radio" className="solicitar-radio" name="categoria" value={5} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>Microfono</p>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h3>Precio:</h3>
                    <label htmlFor="precioInstrumento"></label>
                    <input type="number" name="precio"  placeholder="EJ: 10.000"  value={precio} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h3>¿Tiene descuento?</h3>
                    <fieldset id="flexRadio">
                            <label htmlFor="secundario-terminado"></label>
                            <input type="radio" className="solicitar-radio" name="descuento" value={1} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>Si</p>
                            <label htmlFor="secundario-terminado"></label>
                            <input type="radio"  className="solicitar-radio" name="descuento" value={0} onChange={this.changeHandler}></input>
                            <p>No</p>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h3>Precio con descuento:</h3>
                    <label htmlFor="precioDescuento"></label>
                    <input type="number" name="precioDescuento"  placeholder="EJ: 10.000"  value={precioDescuento} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <h3>Información del Instrumento</h3>
                    <textarea rows="15" cols="30" placeholder="Información.." name="texto"  value={texto} onChange={this.changeHandler}></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label htmlFor="fechaInstrumento">Establece la fecha de creación de tu instrumento</label>
                    <input type="date"  name="fecha"  value={fecha} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="images">
                    <label htmlFor="images">Subí una o varias fotos</label>
                    <input type="file" name="images" id="fotosProyecto" value={images} onChange={this.changeHandler} multiple />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="flex-botones">
                    <button type="submit"> Enviar</button>
                    <button type="reset"> Reiniciar</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            </section>
    </main>
    )}
}

export default Form;
```

**Console Info**

req.body {
nombre: 'Test',
fabricante: 'Test',
precio: '450000',
categoria: '3',
descuento: '0',
precioDescuento: '0',
texto: 'Test',
images: 'C:\fakepath\marshall2.jpg',
fecha: '2022-02-03'
}
req.file undefined

So i dont know what can be making trouble, i have the form encType="multipart/form-data", the multiple attribute for multiples images, and i think i had connect all good, from now thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are sending JSON object from frontend that is why `req.files` is empty.
You need to send your data in `formData` object from frontend.

Change your `submitHandler` with this.

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("nombre", this.state.nombre);
  formData.append("fabricante", this.state.fabricante);
  formData.append("precio", this.state.precio);
  formData.append("categoria", this.state.categoria);
  formData.append("descuento", this.state.descuento);
  formData.append("precioDescuento", this.state.precioDescuento);
  formData.append("texto", this.state.texto);
  formData.append("fecha", this.state.fecha);

  // images will be an array of file objects, you need to loop through array of images and append them to formData with same name
  this.state.images.forEach((img) => {
    formData.append("images", img);
  });

  Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/guardar", formData)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

If you don't know about `FormData` interface, please check this link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Also, you need to change your `changeHandler` because `e.target.value` does not contain file object. It just contains file path. You need to access files through `e.target.files`.

modify your `chnageHandler` with this code.

```
changeHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.target.name === "images") {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.files });
  } else {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
};
```